# How to sort files like `sort` does using the vim's netrw file browser?

Tags: vim, netrw

I would like to have my files sorted this way:

```
abc.c
Makefile
readme.txt
```

but the netrw file browser sorts them like this (using empty sort sequence):

```
Makefile
abc.c
readme.txt
```

How do I fix that?

BTW, it would also be nice to jump to file/directory by typing the first few letters of it's name. Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

netrw indeed can do case-insensitive sorting (which I suppose is what you want): Put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_sort_options = "i"
```

As the netrw file listing is a plain Vim buffer, you can quickly locate entries via the default `/` search command. If you want a solution that filters the list of candidates as you type, you need a different plugin like *FuzzyFinder* or *Command-T*.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, it somehow slipped my mind I could just search the buffer just like a text file.

Comment: This feature is mentioned in netrw's help, too: :help g:netrw_sort_options, at least with v153s.

Answer (score 5):

Sorting in netrw is controlled two ways. You can use the <kbd>s</kbd> key to toggle between sorting by size, time, and name. If that doesn't do what you want, the sorting sequence in netrw can also be controlled by a variable named `g:netrw_sort_sequence`. The default should be suitable for what you want, but it can be changed by setting the variable manually. You can read the Vim help topic `netrw_sort_sequence` for more info (`:help netrw_sort_sequence`)

Answer (score 1):

usually Linux collation is POSIX so i think you need just to change collation like this

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
```

issue the command on the terminal wich runs the VIM or put it in .profile or .bashrc  to be be executed always